# SQL-Server: Error - Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am actually trying to make a script (in Sql Server 2008) to restore one database from one backup file. I made the following code and I am getting an error -

```
Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Exclusive access could not be obtained because 
the database is in use.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

How do I fix this problem  ?

```
IF DB_ID('AdventureWorksDW') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorksDW] 
FILE = N'AdventureWorksDW_Data' 
FROM  
DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
MSSQL10_50.SS2008\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorksDW.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1, 
MOVE N'AdventureWorksDW_Data' 
TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
MSSQL10_50.SS2008\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW.mdf', 
MOVE N'AdventureWorksDW_Log'  
TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
MSSQL10_50.SS2008\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW_0.LDF', 
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10 
END
```

Comment: If I can get this to work, maybe I can make a reliable script to restore multiple databases from one folder. I could not find any reliable code on the net. My code might be reliable because it is generated by SS itself.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I'll assume that if you're restoring a db, you don't care about any existing transactions on that db.  Right?  If so, this should work for you:

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
SET SINGLE_USER
--This rolls back all uncommitted transactions in the db.
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
FROM ...
...
GO
```

Now, one additional item to be aware.  After you set the db into single user mode, someone else may attempt to connect to the db.  If they succeed, you won't be able to proceed with your restore.  It's a race!  My suggestion is to run all three statements at once.

Comment: all three statements in a transaction.

Comment: My SSMS goes into not responding mode whenever i try to access that adventureworks database.

Comment: He actually means `USE master`, not `USER master`.

Comment: Long time ago. Btw, I was just curious to know what is the approach to be used in case I care about transactions. Thanks for your help !

Comment: very well, thanks. it can be use by sqlcommond and i think it's much more logical than using SMO

Comment: Just add `ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorksDW] SET MULTI_USER` at the end to make sure the database back in normal multi user mode.

Comment: @gnaanaa: If the backed up database was in `SINGLE_USER` mode at backup time, it will be in `SINGLE_USER` mode when the backup is restored. If it was in `MULTI_USER` mode at backup time, it will be in `MULTI_USER` mode when it is restored. You make a great point: it's definitely worth checking after the restore is finished. You could also run [RESTORE HEADERONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536(v=sql.110).aspx) on the backup media and check `IsSingleUser` or do bit-wise math on the `Flags` column.

Comment: Will `SINGLE_USER` affect the normal use of live DB?

Answer (score 455):

1. Set the path to restore the file.
2. Click "Options" on the left hand side.
3. Uncheck "Take tail-log backup before restoring"
4. Tick the check box - "Close existing connections to destination database".
   [image]
5. Click OK.

Comment: In my case that checkbox was greyed out.  However I started over and was able to check the box before choosing the source to restore from.  After choosing the backup file the option was greyed out again but the box was still checked and the restore worked.

Comment: Kudos for saving me from typing SQL. The only GUI method among all answers.

Comment: I hope this would have worked for me like others. But for me the check box always remained greyed out. [Andrei Karchueuski's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015577/andrei-karcheuski) [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258011/1184435) below, worked for me.

Comment: I also had to uncheck "Take tail-log backup before restoring" before I was able to restore.

Comment: "Take tail-log backup before restoring" this needs to be unchecked as well. Thanks

Comment: It works!!! confirmed on SSMS v18.5. Thank you sir!

Comment: I don't know why this was ticked for me as I was restoring to a new locations.  Anyway, unticking did it.

Comment: Before I select the file to restore, I went to options and selected to close all existing connections. After that I selected the file to restore. This way it worked for me.

Comment: I had to check the: "Take tail-log backup before restoring" checkbox for mine to work.
But thanks for the answer, it worked.

Answer (score 76):

execute this query before restoring database:

```
alter database [YourDBName] 
set offline with rollback immediate
```

and this one after restoring:

```
  alter database [YourDBName] 
  set online
```

Comment: I ended up switching to this method over SINGLE_USER after pilot application connection beat my query's restore and subsequent MULTI_USER call.  The restore failed to get exclusive access and old db was left in SINGLE_USER mode.

Comment: this worked for me. and it comes online automatically once you restore it.

Comment: This works, and it avoids the race condition in the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 18):

taking original db to offline worked for me

[image: take offline]

Comment: this also worked for me for mgmt studio 2018/2019

Answer (score 16):

For me, the solution is:

1. Check Overwrite the existing database(WITH REPLACE) in optoins tab at left hand side.
2. Uncheck all other options.
3. Select source and destination database.
4. Click ok.

That's it.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I had to uncheck "Take tail-log backup before restore" as well.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following script to find and kill all the opened connections to the database before restoring database.

```
declare @sql as varchar(20), @spid as int

select @spid = min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  where dbid = db_id('<database_name>') 
and spid != @@spid    

while (@spid is not null)
begin
    print 'Killing process ' + cast(@spid as varchar) + ' ...'
    set @sql = 'kill ' + cast(@spid as varchar)
    exec (@sql)

    select 
        @spid = min(spid)  
    from 
        master..sysprocesses  
    where 
        dbid = db_id('<database_name>') 
        and spid != @@spid
end 

print 'Process completed...'
```

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 5):

I just restarted the sqlexpress service and then the restore completed fine

Comment: what can i say about the downvote... for me it worked!

Comment: OP had an issue with his restore script because he didn't take into consideration the fact that his DB might be already in use. The solution was to update his script with the proper commands allowing him exclusive access to the DB.

While restarting the service might have worked for you, that wasn't the appropriate solution to his problem.

Comment: For me (literally) all solutions above didn't work, only this one did.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to set the db to single user mode before attempting to restore, like below, just make sure you're using `master`

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
SET SINGLE_USER
```

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this issue when trying to restore a database on MS SQL Server 2012.

**Here's what worked for me**:

I had to first run the `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` command below on the backup file to list the logical file names:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\my_db_backup.bak'
```

This displayed the **LogicalName** and the corresponding **PhysicalName** of the Data and Log files for the database respectively:

```
LogicalName      PhysicalName               
com.my_db        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.my_db.mdf
com.my_db_log    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.my_db_log.ldf
```

All I had to do was to simply replace the **LogicalName** and the corresponding **PhysicalName** of the Data and Log files for the database respectively in my database restore script:

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE my_db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

    
RESTORE DATABASE my_db
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\my_db_backup.bak'
    WITH REPLACE,
    MOVE 'com.my_db' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.my_db.mdf',
    MOVE 'com.my_db_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.my_db_log.ldf'
GO
    
ALTER DATABASE my_db SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

And the Database Restore task ran successfully:

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 3):

```
Use Master
alter database databasename set offline with rollback immediate;

--Do Actual Restore
RESTORE DATABASE databasename
FROM DISK = 'path of bak file'
WITH MOVE 'datafile_data' TO 'D:\newDATA\data.mdf',
MOVE 'logfile_Log' TO 'D:\newDATA\DATA_log.ldf',replace

alter database databasename set online with rollback immediate;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the DB to single-user mode didn't work for me, but taking it offline, and then bringing it back online did work.  It's in the right-click menu of the DB, under Tasks.

Be sure to check the 'Drop All Active Connections' option in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when there was not enough disk space to restore Db. Cleaning some space solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Vinu M Shankar's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265106/7560349) worked for me.

But I had to check the: ***"Take tail-log backup before restoring"*** checkbox for mine to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I am doing database restore from production to development:

NOTE:  I am doing it via SSAS job to push production database to development daily:

Step1:  Delete previous day backup in development:

```
declare @sql varchar(1024);

set @sql = 'DEL C:\ProdAEandAEXdataBACKUP\AE11.bak'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Step2:  Copy production database to development:

```
declare @cmdstring varchar(1000)
set @cmdstring = 'copy \\Share\SQLDBBackup\AE11.bak C:\ProdAEandAEXdataBACKUP'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstring
```

Step3: Restore by running .sql script

```
SQLCMD -E -S dev-erpdata1 -b -i "C:\ProdAEandAEXdataBACKUP\AE11_Restore.sql"
```

Code that is within AE11_Restore.sql file:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AE11
FROM DISK = N'C:\ProdAEandAEXdataBACKUP\AE11.bak'
WITH MOVE 'AE11' TO 'E:\SQL_DATA\AE11.mdf',
MOVE 'AE11_log' TO 'D:\SQL_LOGS\AE11.ldf',
RECOVERY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : Re-start SQL services and try to restore DB
Solution 2 : Re-start system / server and try to restore DB
Solution 3 : Take back of current DB, Delete the current/destination DB and try to restore DB.

Comment: There can be other databases on the server that do not need to be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when unbeknownst to me, someone else was connected to the database in another SSMS session. After I signed them out the restore completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case although i tried all of the above solutions, the thing that worked, was to restart SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind the data inside the database you wish to recover. If so; under the Options

- Go to Restore Options
- Choose RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY option under
  Recovery State
- Click OK

The above worked for me.