# Unable to delete SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

While trying to delete a SQL database from SSMS, I am not thrown any error but the progress bar just says executing for about 20 minutes now.

I set the database to Single User mode, tried taking it offline, no active SPID's , DBCC opentran() shows no active/open transactions.. yet still the same result when I try to delete it.

Referred to few posts from users with similar problem .. no luck yet.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209499/error-exclusive-access-could-not-be-obtained-because-the-database-is-in-use/22209822#22209822)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting by right clicking, used the below query to drop the database. Works now!

```
USE Master;
GO
DROP DATABASE [MyDB]
GO
```

Note: I could be totally off the mark here but per my understanding the DELETE option just issues a DROP command!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete a system database then you cant, 2 options below to delete user defined databases:

1.Using SQL Server Management Studio
- In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, and then expand that instance.
- Expand Databases, right-click the database to delete, and then click Delete.
- Confirm the correct database is selected, and then click OK.

2. Using T-SQL
   -Connect to the Database Engine.
   -From the Standard bar, click New Query.
   -Copy and paste the following example into the query window and click Execute.

   USE master ;
   GO
   DROP DATABASE DatabaseName ;
   GO

Incase you wish to drop multiple databases:
    USE master ;
    GO
    DROP DATABASE DatabaseName1, DatabaseName2 ;
    GO

Comment: If I had asked "How to delete a SQL database" (which by the way seems like a sacrilegious question), then your answer would have been constructive.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE Master;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS [myDatabase]
```