# How can i use master db in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to create restore db proc. I encountered a problem because i cannot use the command 'use master'. I have try with dynamic SQL but there is no result: 
My code:

```
alter proc dbo.RestoreDB
 (
 @location as varchar(4000) 
 )

as
begin

declare @setMasterDb as varchar(400) = 'use master' 

exec (@setMasterDb);


ALTER DATABASE [testDb] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE [testDb] FROM  DISK = @location WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
ALTER DATABASE [testDb] SET MULTI_USER

end

GO
```

Is there workaround?

Comment: I don't think you need to switch to master to run a restore...

Comment: Also, I don't think switching database contexts in the middle of a Stored Proc is allowed in SQL but I don't have a source for that, just something tickling the back of my brain.

Comment: try addimg go like "  'use master;  go ;"

Comment: As @Kalmino notes, you can't switch database contexts within a stored proc.  Your stored proc can reside in a database other than the one you want to restore.  You may want to create your own DB for this proc or any others you create.  ie `DevMetrics`, `DbaMetrics`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching database contexts (`USE someDBName`) in the middle of a Stored Proc (or function) is not allowed. Also, you do not need to be pointed at the master db context to run a BACKUP/RESTORE, you can be pointed to almost any DB.  To fix your issue, just remove your DB switching and point your query window any DB except the one you want to restore.

EDIT: Updated to point to any DB EXCEPT the one you're trying to restore. Thanks to @DMason for that comment.

Comment: NOTE: You cannot restore a database you are currently connected to.  At a minimum, your connection will have a intent shared lock on the database.  Attempting to restore it will result in `Error - Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use`.  [Additional Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209499/error-exclusive-access-could-not-be-obtained-because-the-database-is-in-use/)